# Expected number of random bitstrings that match a certain prefix

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, expected-value, bit-strings

I am faced with the following problem. Assume I generate $N$ random bitstrings of length $L$ without replacement, that is, no duplicate bitstrings are allowed. Now let $p$ be an arbitrary, but fixed, prefix of length $|p| <L$. In expectation, how many generated bitstrings have the same prefix $p$? I was thinking that the number should be $1/2^{|p|} \cdot N$, but this seems to neglect the fact that I sample the bitstrings without replacement. Is there any other way that I can estimate the number? An upper bound is also completely fine.

Comment: You are correct, because expectation is linear.

Comment: Thanks! But assume that $L= |p|+1$. Then if two strings have prefix $|p|$, then the third string cannot have prefix $|p|$ anymore, right? Because the strings were generated without replacement?

Comment: Yes, and this is not a problem.

Comment: Treat each string as a random variable $X_i$. It has probability $1/2^{|p|}$ to match. Then $E(\sum X_i) = \sum E(X_i) = N/2^{|p|}$. The key is that $E(\sum X_i) = \sum E(X_i)$ is true for any random variables $X_i$, no matter how they might be correlated.